# How should I Create a Batch Menu based on List of Output

Tags: windows, batch-file

I think I may struggle to explain the how I want my batch script to behave so here goes. My script is meant to act as a menu system requiring user input. What I have managed so far is to send a list of datestamps to output to a user. However I am attempting to arrange the script so any timestamp can be selected such as 1,2,3 and based on a prompt for user input. Later I want to save that to a variable in which I can do another operation with afterwards.

So this is what an example of what I can see:

```
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%G IN ('%history% ^| findstr /C:"Start Time:"')      DO (call :subroutine %%G)

:subroutine
echo %1
GOTO :EOF
```

My output now looks like this:

```
20150706232400
20150706232707
20150706232757
20150706233058
20150706233144
```

Any pointers appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could increment an option counter using "set /a". In your subroutine, use the counter as option prefix for display and construct a list of options by appending the count digit to a string variable. Finally, use the CHOICE command to prompt for user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Show menu and store options in an array
echo Available datestamps:
echo/
set i=0
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%G IN ('%history% ^| findstr /C:"Start Time:"') DO (
   set /A i+=1
   echo !i!. %%G
   set "option[!i!]=%%G"
)
echo/

:getChoice
set /P "choice=Enter desired option: "
if "!option[%choice%]!" equ "" echo ERROR: no such option & goto getChoice
set "variable=!option[%choice%]!"

ECHO/
ECHO Selected datestamp: %variable%
```